# how to program IIS 6 and 7 to GZIP the traffic generated by a WCF service hosted in it?

Tags: .net, iis

I know the theory:

1. Activate dynamic content compression
2. Indicate that files with the extension of .svc must be compressed.

But how do I express these demands programmatically? I need to write a utility, which will be run both on IIS6 and IIS7 (two separate utlities may be good too).

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog entry:

http://omaralzabir.com/wcf-does-not-support-compression-out-of-the-box-so-fix-it/

> WCF service and client do not support
>   HTTP Compression out of the box in
>   .NET 3.5 even if you turn on Dynamic
>   Compression in IIS 6 or 7. It has been
>   fixed in .NET 4 but those who are
>   stuck with .NET 3.5 for foreseeable
>   future, you are out of luck.  First of
>   all, it’s IIS fault that it does not
>   enable http compression for SOAP
>   messages even if you turn on Dynamic
>   Compression in IIS 7. Secondly, it’s
>   WCF’s fault that it does not send the
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate header
>   in http requests to the server, which
>   tells IIS that the client supports
>   compression. Thirdly, it’s again WCF
>   fault that even if you make IIS to
>   send back compressed response, WCF
>   can’t process it since it does not
>   know how to decompress it. So, you
>   have to tweak IIS and System.Net
>   factories to make compression work for
>   WCF services. Compression is key for
>   performance since it can dramatically
>   reduce the data transfer from server
>   to client and thus give significant
>   performance improvement if you are
>   exchanging medium to large data over
>   WAN or internet.
>
> There are two steps – first configure
>   IIS, then configure System.Net.
>   There’s no need to tweak anything in
>   WCF like using some Message
>   Interceptor to inject HTTP Headers

Comment: I am using .NET 4, so this is not a problem. You provide interesting info, but how does it answer the question - "how to configure IIS 6 and 7 programmatically to support GZIP compression"?